# Como popular um gráfico de barras com dados em JSON retornados da Action para a View?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma dúvida de como passar o conteúdo do meu JSON para o meu gráfico:

```
//Aqui tenho uma requisição para a minha Action e que retorna um JSON
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("RetornaRankingProdutos")',
    method: "GET"
}).done(function (response) {    
    var option = {
        title: {
            text: 'Relatório de Produtos'
        },
        tooltip: {},
        legend: {
            data: ['Produtos']
        },
        xAxis: {
            data: []
        },
        yAxis: {},
        series: [{
            name: 'Produtos',
            type: 'bar',
            data: []
        }]
    };

    // use configuration item and data specified to show chart
    myChart.setOption(option); 
});
```

Dentro do `response`, há uma lista JSON igual a essa:

```json
[{"NomeProduto":"Suco de Laranja","QuantidadeProduto":2450},
{"NomeProduto":"Suco de Uva","QuantidadeProduto":1000},
{"NomeProduto":"Desinfetante","QuantidadeProduto":860},
{"NomeProduto":"Papel","QuantidadeProduto":1},
{"NomeProduto":"Sabonete","QuantidadeProduto":5740},
{"NomeProduto":"Pasta de Dente","QuantidadeProduto":2300}]
```

A dúvida é a seguinte, como consigo pegar os valores desse JSON e popular o meu gráfico?

Comment: Para criação do gráfico você está utilizando o echarts?

Comment: Opa, isso mesmo, estou usando o echarts.